# How to get Application Name Using Package Name(Assuming i already have the package name)

Tags: java, android

Pls i need android code to convert package name to application name (Assuming i already have the package name e.g. String name = "com.skgames.trafficrider")

Comment: What do you consider the "application name" to be?

Comment: Do you want "trafficrider" or is "com.skgames.trafficrider" the package in which the application is in

Comment: i have multiple strings of application packages i want to convert them to their actual application names

Comment: com.skgames.trafficrider is a package name.  i need codes to convert it to its actual application name @ishnark.  Thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put package name to this function and get AppName (App Label)

```
 public String appName(String pack){
        String Name = null;

        try{
            PackageManager packManager = context.getPackageManager();
            ApplicationInfo app = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(pack, 0);
            Name = packManager.getApplicationLabel(app).toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return Name;
    }
```

Comment: thanks that did it

Answer (score 0):

Try to use next code:

```
ApplicationInfo ai;
try {
    ai = pm.getApplicationInfo("com.skgames.trafficrider", 0);
} catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
    ai = null;
}
final String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");
```